# Typescript version conflict in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript

I have an Angular2 project created with the angular-cli project templates in *Visual Studio Code*. Also, I installed the latest version of Typescript (2.0.3) via npm as well as via the Microsoft link (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593) because I also use *Visual Studio 2015*. However, for some reason the I still get an error message when I start my Angular2 project. Note that even with a standard command prompt running tsc -v will still return 1.0.0.0.

- How does tsc -v determine the version of typescript?
- How do I get rid    of this message in my Angular project and ensure
  it will be using the    latest version of Typescript?

What am  I missing here? Appreciate your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the last version of TypeScript, on both Visual Studios, then you can

1. delete all previous installations which are located in: 
    `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript`.
2. reinstall the latest TypeScript version.

Hopefully everything will work.

Comment: Thanks. Simply deleting the other versions has done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install TypeScript via NPM? If this is the case, try uninstalling it via `npm uninstall -g typescript`. Now reinstall it via `npm install -g typescript` and check if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to allow VScode to only use the version of typescript installed locally.

Drop this in your .vscode/.settings file.

```
    "typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"
```